# Plugin Development for Kdevelop

Tags: c++, kdevelop, kdevelop4

I really love programming in kdevelop4, however it`s quite lacking in language support and other issues, so i would like to developing  extension for it.

however .... i thought i would start with an easy plugin but it seems there is no actual documentation about it(not even a good in code comment) 
just an example that i can seem to get working....( it compiles fine it just does appear  where it should in kdevelop4)

does anyone know about  good documentation on this subject?
or if you made a plugin for kdevelop can you tell me what in short need to be done ?

Comment: I used Google to find http://api.kde.org/extragear-api/kdevelop-apidocs/kdevplatform/html/architecture.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the plugin has been installed to a path in your KDEDIRS env variable, and run kbuildsyscocoa4.